# How can I parse an integer but keep "0" as a valid value using strtol?

Tags: c

This might seem super obvious but strtol provides a response to the parsed integer -- but it's 0 on fail. What if the integer I parsed is 0?

Comment: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t436175-strtol-and-zero.html

Comment: Make sure you set `errno` to `0` before your call to `strtol()`. I have had a crazy bug caused by checking a stale `errno` value.

Comment: There's an ERRNO for out of range, but I don't see one for invalid?

Comment: You might like to read an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`errno` is only guaranteed to be set in the case of over/underflow (to `ERANGE`). For other errors you must check the value of `endptr`. Quoting C89:

```
long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

> If the subject sequence is empty or does not have the expected
>   form, no conversion is performed; the value of nptr is stored in the
>   object pointed to by endptr, provided that endptr is not a null
>   pointer.

Normally endptr is set to point to the next character in the input string after the last character converted, so if it's the equal to the beginning of the string, you can be sure no conversion has been performed. For example,

```
char *nptr = "not a number", *endptr;
long n = strtol(nptr, &endptr, 10);
assert(nptr != endptr); //false
```

POSIX contains a handy extension which also sets `errno` to `EINVAL` in this case, but this is nonstandard.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only CORRECT cross-platform answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to `man strtol`:

> If no conversion could be performed, 0 is returned and the global variable errno is set to
>        EINVAL (the last feature is not portable across all platforms).

Is that not the case on you platform?  If so, what platform are you on?

Comment: I'm on Windows, I'm not getting EINVAL or ERANGE errors. I'm just getting errno 0 and '0' back for something like 'a' for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the presence of `errno` as indicated in the example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) on CppReference.

Comment: errno only appears to appear when it's out of range?